# "Morra Sheldon" ou "Morra, Sheldon"?

Tags: verbos, conjugações, vocativos

Quando se conjuga o imperativo dum verbo (faz, faça, tenha, digitai, etc.), usa-se  "Conjugação Pronome" (faz tu, faça você/ela/ele, tenha você/ele/ela, digitai vós, etc).

Então, ao meu ver, "Morra Sheldon" e "Morra, Sheldon" estão ambas corretas, ainda que por motivos diferentes.

Estão as duas corretas? Se não, qual delas é a certa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neste caso, a frase correta seria: "Morra, *Sheldon*", uma vez que *Sheldon* tem a função de **vocativo** na frase:

> O **vocativo** é o termo que tem a função de **chamar**, **invocar** ou **interpelar** dentro da oração. **Não possui relação sintática com outros termos da oração,** não pertencendo, portanto, nem ao sujeito, nem ao predicado; porém, relaciona-se com a segunda pessoa do discurso. [(Ver mais)](https://www.infoescola.com/portugues/vocativo/)

Tratando-se de um vocativo, **tem de ser isolado, por vírgula, do resto da frase** - ainda que esta regra seja muitas vezes ignorada: [A vírgula isolando o vocativo: uma regra em vias de extinção?](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/pelourinho/a-virgula-isolando-o-vocativo-uma-regra-em-vias-de-extincao/2890); daí "Morra Sheldon" não parecer errado, embora o esteja.

A regra existe para evitar ambiguidade. Vejamos casos mais evidentes:

1. **Maria** faz os trabalhos de casa.
2. **Maria,** faz os trabalhos de casa.

Na primeira frase, **Maria** exerce a função de **sujeito**; o narrador está a constatar que a Maria está a fazer os trabalhos de casa. No segundo, contudo, **Maria** é um **vocativo** e está-se a dar uma ordem à Maria (para ela fazer os trabalhos de casa).

Assim, quando usamos um vocativo para nos dirigirmos a alguém - algo que é comum fazer-se quando usamos o imperativo e se está a dar uma ordem - temos obrigatoriamente de utilizar a vírgula para isolar o vocativo.

P.S.: Se tiver dúvidas sobre se *Sheldon* é ou não um vocativo, repare que estaria igualmente correto dizer: "*Sheldon*, morra" (preservando-se a vírgula) ou simplesmente "Morra!", sem qualquer perda de significado (pois *Sheldon*, sendo um vocativo,  não está a exercer nenhuma função sintática).

Comment: Completamente de acordo.Tal como no teu exemplo da Maria, em *Morra Sheldon*, *Sheldon* é também sujeito: a frase é equivalente a *Que morra Sheldon* = *Que Sheldon morra*. Compara com frases do tipo *valha-me Deus* ou *fiquem os dedos, vão-se os anéis*.